# Using the Haxe While Loop to Remove All of a Value from an Array

Tags: performance, while-loop, haxe

I'm wanting to remove all of a possibly duplicated value in an array. At the moment I'm using the `remove(x:T):Bool` function in a while loop, but I'm wondering about the expression part.

I've started by using:

```
function removeAll(array:Array<String>, element:String):Void
    while (array.remove(element)) {}
```

but I'm wondering if any of these lines would be more efficient:

```
while (array.remove(element)) continue;
while (array.remove(element)) true;
while (array.remove(element)) 0;
```

or if it makes any kind of difference.

I'm guessing that using `continue` is less efficient because it actually has to do something, `true` and `0` are slightly more efficient, but still do something, and `{}` would probably be most efficient.

Does anyone have any background information on this?

Answer (score 3):

While other suggested `filter`, it will create a new instance of list/array which may cause your other code to lose reference.

If you loop `array.remove`, it is going to loop through all the elements in the front of the array every time, which is not so performant.

IMO a better approach is to use a reverse `while` loop:

```
var i = array.length;
while(--i >= 0)
  if(array[i] == element) array.splice(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make any difference. In fact, there's not even any difference in the generated code for the `{}`, `0` and `false` cases: they all end up generating `{}`, at least on the JS target.

However, you could run into issues if you have a large array with many duplicates: in that case, `remove()` would be called many times, and it has to iterate over the array each time (until it finds a match, that is). In that case, it's probably more efficient to use [`filter()`](https://api.haxe.org/Array.html?#filter):

```
function removeAll(array:Array<String>, element:String):Array<String>
    return array.filter(function(e) return e != element);
```

Personally, I also find this to be a bit more elegant than your `while`-loop with an empty body. But again, it depends on the use case: this does create a new array, and thus causes an allocation. Usually, that's not worth worrying about, but if you for instance do it in the update loop of a game, you might want to avoid it.

Comment: Well it is getting called every frame, but I'm expecting the array to have less that 10-15 elements (and shouldn't generally have duplicate values).

What about something like `function removeAll(arr:Array<String>, el:String):Void { arr = Lambda.filter(array, function(v) {return v != el;}); }`?

Comment: Wait no, `Lambda.filter()` returns `List<T>` which is different to `Array<T>`. Nevermind then.

Comment: `array.remove()` should be just fine then. :)

Comment: Wait no I've found an even better thing I'm writing a comment!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the expression part of the `while` loop, it seems that it's just set to empty brases (`{}`) when compiled so it doesn't really matter what you do.

In terms of performance, a much better solution is the Method 2 from the following:

```
class Test
{
    static function main()
    {
        var thing:Array<String> = new Array<String>();
        for (index in 0...1000)
        {
            thing.push("0");
            thing.push("1");
        }

        var copy1 = thing.copy();
        var copy2 = thing.copy();

        trace("epoch");

        while (copy1.remove("0")) {}

        trace("check");

        // Method 2.
        copy2 = [
            for (item in Lambda.filter(copy2, function(v)
            {return v != "0";}))
                item
        ];

        trace("check");
    }
}
```

which can be seen [here](https://try.haxe.org/#D0468"Try Haxe example."). For 200,000 one-character elements in an `Array<String>`, Method 2 takes 0.017s while Method 1 takes 44.544s.

Comment: If you're going this way, you can drop Lambda.filter too: https://try.haxe.org/#24bdE (6ms vs 30ms for 200.000 elements)

Comment: `Lambda.filter()` actually seems to be a bit slower than the `array.filter()` method I suggested: https://try.haxe.org/#6A8E4 (which makes sense, considering its implementation)

Comment: Note that performance on large lists isn't really too relevant for your use case (where the list is very small) - in an update loop it's probably more important to avoid allocations. Regarding that, the `Lambda.filter` solution is probably the worst solution out of all of them, since a new `List` is created, a `ListNode` will be allocated for each element, and then you create an `Array` from that. It's hard to measure GC impact in benchmarks.

Comment: Another approach could be (if applicable) to avoid adding duplicates in the first place, since this cleanup happens at each frame.

Answer (score 0):

For large arrays it will be faster to use a temporary array and then assign that back after populating ( method3 in try )?

OR

If you don't want to use a temp you can assign back and splice ( method4 in try )?

https://try.haxe.org/#5f80c

Both are more verbose codewise as I setup vars, but on mac seems faster at runtime, summary of my method3 approach:

`while( i < l ) { if( ( s = copy[ i++ ] ) != '0' ) arr[ j++ ] = s;
        copy = arr;`

am I missing something obvious against these approaches?